# Boost hana fold_left lambda call by reference

Tags: c++, boost-hana

I want to traverse through a multimap (map of maps) e.g.: `map<int,map<char, string>>` with the help of boost hana. The lambda function `at` can't take a reference type `&map` (compile error: non-const reference), thus, I can't load or store elements in the multimap.

```
   template <typename T_Map, typename T_Tuple>
   auto& traverse(T_Map &map, T_Tuple &keys){
      auto at = [](auto &map, auto key) -> auto& {
          return map[key];
      };     
      return hana::fold_left(keys, map, at);
   }
```

Is it possible to solve this problem with boost::hana like I did ? Or is there some other way ?

**Update 1:**

Previous Solution without hana need parameter packs. But I need a function that accepts keys as tuple.

```
template <typename T_Map, typename T, typename... Ts>
auto& traverse(T_Map &map, T key, Ts... keys){
    return traverse(map[key], keys...);
}

template <typename T_Map, typename T>
auto& traverse(T_Map& map, T key){
    return map[key];

}
```

Comment: Folding a sequence of keys with the `at` function you present hardly makes sense. It only makes sense if the sequence of keys you have is `[key1, ..., keyN]` and the map you have is of the form `map<key1, map<key2, ... map<keyN, value>>>`. And then the result of your `fold_left` would be `value`, which is probably not what you expect. Hence, could you please explain what you're actually trying to achieve, and perhaps I could shed light on the better way to do it? Are you trying to get a list of the maps (which are values inside the multimap)  associated to each key in in the `keys` sequence?

Comment: Actually I expect what you have explained in your first three sentences. So there are keys `[key1, ..., keyN]` and the map of the form `map<key1, map<key2, ... map<keyN, value>>>` and I'd like to obtain `&value`. I posted the previous solutions as an update above, but I need to use tuples instead of paramter packs. Therefore the use of hana.

Comment: Sorry for misinterpreting your question. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed two bugs that prevented your use case from working properly. Here's
a minimal complete example that currently works on master:

```
#include <boost/hana/at_key.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/fold_left.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/integral_constant.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/map.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/pair.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/range.hpp>

#include <cassert>
namespace hana = boost::hana;


auto at = [](auto& map, auto key) -> auto& {
    return map[key];
};

template <typename Map, typename Keys>
auto& traverse(Map& map, Keys const& keys){
    return hana::fold_left(keys, map, at);
}

int main() {
    auto xs = hana::make_map(hana::make_pair(hana::int_c<0>,
                hana::make_map(hana::make_pair(hana::int_c<1>,
                    hana::make_map(hana::make_pair(hana::int_c<2>,
                        hana::make_map(hana::make_pair(hana::int_c<3>, 10))))))));

    int& i = traverse(xs, hana::range_c<int, 0, 4>);
    assert(i == 10);
    i = 99;
    assert(traverse(xs, hana::range_c<int, 0, 4>) == 99);
}
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you the quick help. Your work on hana is brilliant !

Comment: Glad I could help. Thanks to you for trying the library out!

Comment: `using namespace hana;` might make this a little easier to read

Comment: @TemplateRex Easier to read, yes. But since this is an example, it is helpful to see exactly which functions come from hana and which do not